# command for debugging and log packer build in windows

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, packer

I want to log in a file my verbose debugging `packer build ubuntu-14.04-amd64.json` which don't want to install few tool in my script.

**What is the exact command for run a build with debugging and logging in a file the build packer ?**

I also run `PACKER_LOG=1 packer build -debug ubuntu-14.04-amd64.json` or try to export variable shell but not run

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**(UNIX)**

```
$ export PACKER_LOG_PATH="/var/log/packer.log"
$ export PACKER_LOG=10
$ packer build -debug ubuntu_64.json
```

**(WINDOWS)**

```
$ set PACKER_LOG=10
$ set PACKER_LOG_PATH=c:\temp\packer log
$ packer build -debug ubuntu_64.json
```

Now You have a file which contain all messages appear in console during the process of building.

Comment: This answer can be confirmed according to official Packer documentation https://www.packer.io/docs/debugging